# How to do memory heap size test in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I have 2 version of data.

1. Just array of json objects.
2. The same array, with references.

For example, if I have 1000 objects with the same manager:

```
{
    "_id": 101,
    "manager": {
        "_id": 12160,
        "name": "name"
    }
}
```

I change the manager object to be reference.

```
managers[12160] = {
            "_id": 12160,
            "name": "name"
        }

array.forEach(item => item.manager = managers[12160])
```

So, I want to validate that it  really decrease the memory size. Any idea to how to do that?

Comment: Memory management is not a responsibility of your application, that is the responsibility of the javascript engine that Node.JS uses. There is not even a guarantee that this code is going to have any immediate impact on the heap size, that all depends on how the javascript engine collects garbage. Assume it works, write tests that test your code instead.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the previous answer,
the proposed sample code most probably will not have any noticeable effect on the heap, 
but you can use Node modules 'os' and 'v8' to read some stats from your environment,
here is some example:

```
    var stats = {
     'Load Average' : os.loadavg().join(' '),
     'CPU Count' : os.cpus().length,
     'Free Memory' : os.freemem(),
     'Current Malloced Memory' : v8.getHeapStatistics().malloced_memory,
     'Peak Malloced Memory' : v8.getHeapStatistics().peak_malloced_memory,
     'Allocated Heap Used (%)' : Math.round((v8.getHeapStatistics().used_heap_size / v8.getHeapStatistics().total_heap_size) * 100),
     'Available Heap Allocated (%)' : Math.round((v8.getHeapStatistics().total_heap_size / v8.getHeapStatistics().heap_size_limit) * 100),
     'Uptime' : os.uptime()+' Seconds'
   };
```